# bouncing counter not giving proper results

Tags: java, javafx

hey I’m doing this just for fun, but I want to count each time the circle lands perfectly in the corner (like when we all used to watch the dvd symbol on the screensaver pop into the corner and dies when it got close, but didn't. I want to know for sure). My counter seems to be counting twice when it should be counting once. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it.

```
 import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
    import javafx.util.Duration;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;

    public class EllipsePane extends Pane {
      public final double radius = 20;
      private double x = radius, y = radius;
      private double dx = 1, dy = 1;
      private Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
      private Timeline animation;
      private Button btCountRead = new Button("How many times has it landed perfectly in the corner?");
      private int i = 0;

      public EllipsePane() {
        ellipse.setFill(Color.GREEN); // Set ball color
        ellipse.setRadiusX(radius);
        ellipse.setRadiusY(radius);
        getChildren().add(ellipse); // Place a ball into this pane
        getChildren().add(btCountRead);

        // Create an animation for moving the ball
        animation = new Timeline(
          new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> moveBall()));
        animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        animation.play(); // Start animation
      }

      public void play() {
        animation.play();
      }

      public void pause() {
        animation.pause();
      }

      public void increaseSpeed() {
        animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 100);
      }

      public void decreaseSpeed() {
        animation.setRate(
          animation.getRate() > 0 ? animation.getRate() - 100 : 0);
      }

      public DoubleProperty rateProperty() {
        return animation.rateProperty();
      }

      protected void moveBall() {
        // Check boundaries
        if (x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius) {
          dx *= -1; // Change ball move direction
        }
        if (y < radius || y > getHeight() - radius) {
          dy *= -1; // Change ball move direction
        }

        // Adjust ball position
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        ellipse.setCenterX(x);
        ellipse.setCenterY(y);

        if ((ellipse.getCenterX() - radius == 0 && ellipse.getCenterY() - radius == 0) ||
          (ellipse.getCenterX() - radius == 0 && ellipse.getCenterY() + radius == getHeight()) ||
          (ellipse.getCenterX() + radius == getWidth() && ellipse.getCenterY() + radius == getHeight()) ||
          (ellipse.getCenterX() - radius == getWidth() && ellipse.getCenterY() - radius == 0)){
          i++;
          /*btCountRead.setOnAction( e ->*/ System.out.println(i);
        }
      }
    }
```

this is the second file i used. both are needed.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class BounceBallControl extends Application {
  @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    EllipsePane ellipsePane = new EllipsePane(); // Create a ball pane

    // Pause and resume animation
    ellipsePane.setOnMousePressed(e -> ellipsePane.pause());
    ellipsePane.setOnMouseReleased(e -> ellipsePane.play());

    // Increase and decrease animation   
    ellipsePane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
      if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
        ellipsePane.increaseSpeed();
      } 
      else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
        ellipsePane.decreaseSpeed();
      }
    });

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(ellipsePane, 250, 150);
    primaryStage.setTitle("BounceBallControl"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    // Must request focus after the primary stage is displayed
    ellipsePane.requestFocus();
  }

  /**
   * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
   * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code into a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will lower the barrier for answering, and you'll likely receive better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition for incrementing the count is pretty fragile. I think what happens is that in one "frame" the ellipse is exactly in the corner, which increments the count, but doesn't change either direction (since you use strict inequalities in the test to change direction). On the next frame the ellipse moves `(dx, dy)` off screen, and you change both directions, and on the following frame you are back exactly in the corner.

I would make the test for incrementing the counter just "Do we change horizontal and vertical direction in the same 'frame'?". I.e.:

```
protected void moveBall() {
    // Check boundaries

    boolean changedHorizontal = false ;

    if (x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius) {
        dx *= -1; // Change ball move direction
        changedHorizontal = true ;
    }
    if (y < radius || y > getHeight() - radius) {
        dy *= -1; // Change ball move direction
        if (changedHorizontal) {
            i++ ;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    // Adjust ball position
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
    ellipse.setCenterX(x);
    ellipse.setCenterY(y);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I agree with @James_D's answer... you should choose that one as it is more direct and optimial.  But just for fun, let's add a little debug info to your output and see what is going on.

The answer for "double increments" is that the logic is incrementing "i" both when ENTERING a corner and then immediately when EXITING the same corner.  @James_D hit on an easy way to Greatly simplify the "did we get a perfect corner hit?" logic.

But first, the more interesting part of this is how to find out, so I hacked up some debugging info to add to the program in the hopes you will find it helpful.

Here I will describe some of the things I wanted to track in the debug output, most of these are done by adding some private instance variables to EllipsePane.java (see modified code, way below).

```
"moveBallCnt" is new, it counts each time your moveBall() method
is called, whether or not "i" changed.

"i" is just your original i, note that we (currently) only print
out a stats line (e.g. call debugStats() whenever "i" is incremented).

"x" is the original's value of "x".

"lastx" is the value of "x" during the *previous* call to
moveBall(); I thought it would be helpful to see what 'x' has
been doing over time.

Same thing for "y" and "lasty" and so on.

"hit" indicates which part of your original "if-else" logic
was hit, I broke that out to just be "A" for the first one,
"B" for the 2nd one and so on.
```

So.  The following output is generated by the debugHeader() and the debugStats() methods I added to EllipsPane.java (see code, below).

You can see what lastx, lasty etc. are updated at the end of the movBall() method (see code, below).
Now having set all that up, lets see what we get for output.  (Note that I'm running this in virtualbox on ubuntu, hence the "libGL errors".)

```
$ java BounceBallControl 
pci id for fd 6: 80ee:beef, driver (null)
libGL error: core dri or dri2 extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
 moveBallCnt. hit:      i |      x |  lastX |      y |  lastY |     dx | lastdx |     dy | lastdy |
        5933.   B:      1 |  20.00 |  21.00 | 130.00 | 129.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |
        5935.   B:      2 |  20.00 |  19.00 | 130.00 | 131.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |
       11869.   A:      3 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |
       11871.   A:      4 |  20.00 |  19.00 |  20.00 |  19.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |
       17805.   B:      5 |  20.00 |  21.00 | 130.00 | 129.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |
       17807.   B:      6 |  20.00 |  19.00 | 130.00 | 131.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |
       23741.   A:      7 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |
       23743.   A:      8 |  20.00 |  19.00 |  20.00 |  19.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |
       29677.   B:      9 |  20.00 |  21.00 | 130.00 | 129.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |
       29679.   B:     10 |  20.00 |  19.00 | 130.00 | 131.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |
       35613.   A:     11 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |
       35615.   A:     12 |  20.00 |  19.00 |  20.00 |  19.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |
       41549.   B:     13 |  20.00 |  21.00 | 130.00 | 129.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |
       41551.   B:     14 |  20.00 |  19.00 | 130.00 | 131.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |
       47485.   A:     15 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |
       47487.   A:     16 |  20.00 |  19.00 |  20.00 |  19.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |
       53421.   B:     17 |  20.00 |  21.00 | 130.00 | 129.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |
       53423.   B:     18 |  20.00 |  19.00 | 130.00 | 131.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |
       59357.   A:     19 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |
 moveBallCnt. hit:      i |      x |  lastX |      y |  lastY |     dx | lastdx |     dy | lastdy |
       59359.   A:     20 |  20.00 |  19.00 |  20.00 |  19.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |
       65293.   B:     21 |  20.00 |  21.00 | 130.00 | 129.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |
       65295.   B:     22 |  20.00 |  19.00 | 130.00 | 131.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |
       71229.   A:     23 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  20.00 |  21.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |  -1.00 |
       71231.   A:     24 |  20.00 |  19.00 |  20.00 |  19.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 |   1.00 |  -1.00 | ^C
$
```

So, what does this tell us?
Every time "i" changes, it happens between neighboring calls to moveBall().
For example, the first set of "neighbors" are moveBall=5,933 and moveBall=5,935.  Looks like your "corner-hit?" logic is tripping twice, once when it enters the corner, then again once when it leaves the corner.

Next, consider the changes of "dx vs. lastdx" and "dy vs lastdy".
For example, on moveBallCnt=5,933  dx is the same as lastdx.
Coming out of it, on moveBallCnt=5,935 dx has changed from -1 to 1.

Note that running it with debugStats() only printing when "i" changes a modest amount of output, easy enough to see in a display window.

This next change will generate a ton of output, but it is interesting: uncomment the

```
//DEBUG: change += "dx";
```

and

```
//DEBUG: change += "dy"
```

lines for your dx / dy manipulation will generate a debugStats() call with pretty much every call to moveBall().
If you do this you may want to run it something like the following:

```
$java BounceBallContorl > run.dat
```

Let it go for a while, long enough to get a few corner hits.
Then hit ^C and open run.dat in a text editor, look for hits where you have "B:" or "A:" and "dxyd:" to study the pattern of dx & dy changes around it.

If you do that, you'll find an interesting optimization.
It looks like you can declare a "perfect corner hit" if both dx and dy change in a given call to moveBox().
That would greatly simplify your if-logic.
Note there are a number of ways you could see if both dx and dy change.
I'm using the temp-var

```
String change="";
```

just to make the debugStats() printout more displayable.

You could use the change var as-is and declare "perfect corner" when change.equals("dxdy").

You could also set booleans for "dx_change" and "dy_change" and declare "perfect corner" when both are true.

Or maybe keep a counter for each delta change during a call to moveBall() and declare "perfect corner" when you "deltaChangeCnt == 2".

Good luck, and happy programming.

=== begin modified EllipsPane.java ===

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class EllipsePane extends Pane {
   public final double radius = 20;
   private double x = radius, y = radius;
   private double dx = 1, dy = 1;
   private Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
   private Timeline animation;
   //private Button btCountRead = new Button("How many times has it landed perfectly in the corner?");
   private Button btCountRead = new Button("corner cnt:");
   private int i = 0;
   private double lasti = 0, lastx, lasty, lastdx, lastdy; // added for debugging.
   private long moveBallCnt = 0;

   public EllipsePane() {
      ellipse.setFill(Color.GREEN); // Set ball color
      ellipse.setRadiusX(radius);
      ellipse.setRadiusY(radius);
      getChildren().add(ellipse); // Place a ball into this pane
      getChildren().add(btCountRead);

      // Create an animation for moving the ball

      animation = new Timeline(
         new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> moveBall()));
      animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
      animation.play(); // Start animation
      debugHeaders();
   }

   public void play() {
      animation.play();
   }

   public void pause() {
      animation.pause();
   }

   public void increaseSpeed() {
      animation.setRate(animation.getRate() + 100);
   }

   public void decreaseSpeed() {
      animation.setRate(
         animation.getRate() > 0 ? animation.getRate() - 100 : 0);
   }

   public DoubleProperty rateProperty() {
      return animation.rateProperty();
   }

   protected void moveBall() {
      // Check boundaries
      String change = "";
      if (x < radius || x > getWidth() - radius) {
         dx *= -1; // Change ball move direction
         //DEBUG: change += "dx";
      }
      if (y < radius || y > getHeight() - radius) {
         dy *= -1; // Change ball move direction
         //DEBUG: change += "dy";
      }
      if( !change.isEmpty() ) {
         debugStats( change );
      }

      // Adjust ball position
      x += dx;
      y += dy;
      ellipse.setCenterX(x);
      ellipse.setCenterY(y);

      String hitType = null;
      // Let's start by splitting up the if-logic so we can see what is actually firing.
      // We'll add temp-var "hitType" to see which if expression fires.
      // (Also... just for fun, since the "center" of the elipse is x & y, you could
      // rewrite the following in terms of "x" and "y"):
      if( x - radius == 0 && y - radius == 0 ) {
         hitType = "A";
      } else if( x - radius == 0 && y + radius == getHeight())  {
         hitType = "B";
      } else if( x + radius == getWidth() && y + radius == getHeight() )  {
         hitType = "C";
      } else if( x - radius == getWidth() && y - radius == 0 ) {
         hitType = "D";
      }
      //original: if ((ellipse.getCenterX() - radius == 0 && ellipse.getCenterY() - radius == 0) ||
      //original:   hitType = "A";
      //original: else if( ellipse.getCenterX() - radius == 0 && ellipse.getCenterY() + radius == getHeight())  {
      //original:   hitType = "B";
      //original: } else if( ellipse.getCenterX() + radius == getWidth() && ellipse.getCenterY() + radius == getHeight() )  {
      //original:   hitType = "C";
      //original: } else if( ellipse.getCenterX() - radius == getWidth() && ellipse.getCenterY() - radius == 0 ) {
      //original:   hitType = "D";
      //original: }

      if( hitType != null ) {
         // something fired, let's print out some background info...
         i++;
         if( 0 == (i % 20 ) ) {
         debugHeaders();  // do this so they don't scroll offscreen.
         }
         debugStats( hitType );
      }
      // update our "last" values each time through the moveBall() method whether or not anything fired.
      lasti = i;
      lastx = x; lastdx = dx;
      lasty = y; lastdy = dy;
      moveBallCnt++; // count each time moveBall() is called.
      //{
      //  /*btCountRead.setOnAction( e ->*/
      //}
   }

   public void debugHeaders() {
      System.out.printf("%12s.%4s: %6s | %6s | %6s | %6s | %6s | %6s | %6s | %6s | %6s |\n"
         ,"moveBallCnt"
         ,"hit"
         ,"i"
         ,"x",  "lastX"
         ,"y",  "lastY"
         ,"dx", "lastdx"
         ,"dy", "lastdy" );
   }

   public void debugStats( String hitType ) {
      System.out.printf("%12d.%4s: %6d | %6.2f | %6.2f | %6.2f | %6.2f | %6.2f | %6.2f | %6.2f | %6.2f |\n"
         , moveBallCnt
         , hitType
         , i
         , x,  lastx
         , y,  lasty
         , dx, lastdx
         , dy, lastdy );
   }
}
```

=== end modified EllipsePane.java ===